# Determining whether piecewise function y[n] = {x[n] if n even, -x[n] if n odd} is time invariant

Tags: signal, signal-processing

$$
y[n] =
\begin{cases}
 x[n], & \text{if }n\text{ is even} \\
-x[n], & \text{if }n\text{ is odd}
\end{cases}
$$

My usual way of solving time invariance problems is to do this: 
$$y[n-m] =  x[n-m]$$

but I have no idea how to deal with the function splitting off into 2 cases.

Comment: Try your way when *m* = 1. Remember that if *n* is even, then *n*-1 is odd, and vice versa. Or another way to look at it, *n* is your time variable. And the function is explicitly varying for different values of the time variable. So do you think it is "time invariant"?

Comment: Shouldn't this have been asked in the [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) or [Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: which site is better for signals and systems questions? I thought that this wasn't really mathematics related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You can re-write \$y[n]\$ as

$$y[n] = (-1)^{n}x[n]$$

which has only one case. \$(-1)^{n} = 1\$ if \$n\$ is even so \$y[n] = x[n]\$ if \$n\$ is even, and \$(-1)^{n} = -1\$ if \$n\$ is odd so \$y[n] = -x[n]\$ if \$n\$ is odd. Does that help?

Comment: not enough rep yet, but thank you, that makes complete sense!